# What's the fastest way to find and delete duplicate nodes inside XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

XML file has structure like this

```
<Nodes>
   <Node> one </Node>
   <Node> two </Node>
   <Node> three </Node>
   <Node> three </Node>
</Nodes>
```

Since xml file has more than 30000 nodes I'm looking for fastest way to find and delete duplicate nodes.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet` :

```
var values = new HashSet<string>();
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("path");

foreach(var node in xmlDocument.Root.Elements("Node").ToList())
{
   if(!values.Add((string)node)) 
       node.Remove();
}

xmlDocument.Save("newpath");
```

Another way is to implement an `IEqualityComparer` for `XElement` class then use `Distinct` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try an XSLT 2.0 transformation:

```
<Nodes xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3..org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="2.0">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="/Nodes/Node" group-by=".">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
</Nodes>
```

You can run that from C# using Saxon or XmlPrime.