# Fastest way to remove XML nodes with C#

Tags: c#, xml

Supposed that I have an in-memory XElement as below:

```
<ROOT>
    <CHILD1 />
    <CHILD1 />
    <CHILD2 />
    <CHILD2 />
    <CHILD1 />
    <CHILD1 />
    <CHILD3 />
    <CHILD3 />
</ROOT>
```

All CHILD1 nodes must be deleted except the last one.

The tree has approx ~1 million nodes & 70% of them are CHILD1 nodes. What is the most efficient way to remove these unused nodes in a timely fashion? I tried the following:

```
List<XElement> remNodes = root.Elements("CHILD1").ToList();
remNodes.RemoveRange(0, remNodes.Length - 1)
```

and also the old & easy way:

```
XElement[] remNodes = root.Elements("CHILD1").ToArray();
for (i=0;i<remNodes.Length-1;i++) remNodes[i].Remove();
```

Both took too much time to complete  (~5 hours). Is there any quicker method?

**UPDATE 1**

Tried to save the last node & remove as below:

```
XElement savedNode = remNodes.Last();
savedNode.Save("to_file");
root.Elements("CHILD1").Remove();
```

But it looks like the time taken is the same.

**UPDATE 2**

Finally, I'd ended up making the task complete in a timely fashion (less then 1 minute). I used an approach of saving valid nodes to file, then remove the whole tree & reload tree with saved nodes. Thanks @Matthew Haugen for your idea. Would you mind adding your answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Might it be easier to write the elements you *do* want to keep to a new file, rather than even bothering to remove them?

Comment: You could try grouping the child nodes and deleting them in chunks.
Optionally, perhaps the following might help get you closer to a solution. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002106/whats-the-fastest-way-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-nodes-inside-xml

Comment: Are you sure the code that was deleting the nodes took that long? A million records is actually not that many, and I would be very surprised if it took that long to process, just from removing nodes.

Comment: @Zipper I simplified the tree to make the question clear, in real world it is a lots more complex & consumes 5GB memory. Any idea?

Comment: @JamesShaw Did you mean using XSLT? Could this be used with in-memory XML?

Comment: For such a large data set, you should not be reading it all in memory, you should be using other classes such as the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` to process your data. 5GB of data is a lot, especially with all the overheads of other details that are tracked in the implementation (such as parent/child relationships, etc.).

Comment: Have you tried XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I'd ended up making the task complete in a timely fashion (less then 1 minute). I used an approach of saving valid nodes to file, then remove the whole tree & reload tree with saved nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
root.Elements("CHILD1").Reverse().Skip(1).Remove();
```

Comment: Skip() would be a good thing to know. But are you sure this will faster than root.Elements("CHILD1").Remove()? In my UPDATE 1. Remove all add no advantage to the performance.

Comment: @RyanB Your `root.Elements("CHILD1").Remove()` will remove the last node - and you said you were trying to keep it, along with the other elements.

Comment: Yes, but I'd backed it up before I remove all include last node.

Answer (score 0):

I threw this together. 200000 child elements. Doesn't take too long but I am not quite sure how many you are attempting to work with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = DummyData();

            //DeleteNodes("child1", data);
            DeleteNodes2("child1", data);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DeleteNodes(string node, string xml)
        {
            var values = new HashSet<string>();
            var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            foreach (var n in xmlDocument.Root.Elements(node).ToList())
            {
                if (!values.Add((string)node))
                    n.Remove();
            }
        }

        static void DeleteNodes2(string node, string xml)
        {
            var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            xmlDocument.Root
                     .Elements(node).GroupBy(g => g).SelectMany(f => f).Reverse().Skip(1).Remove();

            //Test to see how many are left
            var duplicates = xmlDocument.Root
                     .Elements(node).GroupBy(g => g).ToList(); 
        }

        static string DummyData()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            TextWriter w = new StringWriter();


            var writer = new XmlTextWriter(w);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");

            for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
            {
                int rand = r.Next(3);
                writer.WriteStartElement(string.Format("child{0}", rand.ToString()));
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();

            return w.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

If this is indeed faster, then the credit should go to Chuck there. This is only a spin off of what he suggested.

Comment: My tree have 1195000 level 1 nodes & each of them also have child nodes. The whole tree is fit in ~5GB of memory. I did not try your solution since I tried with root.Elements(node).Remove(), it took the same time with my first attempt. I guess .NET getting crazy on the task of re-populate the tree. However, I did get over the issue by my latest attempt. Please have a look at my UPDATE 2.

Comment: I am glad you came to a solution.  Yes that did make the most sense but it seemed that you were more keen on keeping the original methodology. Good luck!